# Странное отображение языка в android studio

Tags: android-studio, локализация

Давно не заходил в Android Studio, зашёл и вижу такую картину[image: Безобразие]

Несколько раз переустанавливал, скачал последнюю версию. Толку нет. Предлагали удалить Bizagi Studio, но у меня его нет. Есть Visual Studio, но не думаю, что из-за него

Comment: Попробуйте описанное тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405663/android-studio-always-garbled

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, большое спасибо! Реально помогло. Я просто переустановил шрифты на ноутбуке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установил файл REG

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"="segoeuil.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"="seguisb.ttf"
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"=-
```

И перезагрузил компьютер